# Associating multiple single instances of the same model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, model

I am working on a project in which there are events, which each relate to two single forms on two separate relations – booking and survey. These forms are identically constructed, making it seem unnecessary to use two entirely distinct form models – I instead wanted to use a polymorphic relation, but it appears that isn't possible.

**What is the appropriate way to structure this relationship?**

- Events have one or no booking form
- Events have one or no survey form
- Forms are a separate, single table

**What I have tried:**

- Polymorphic relationship: Not compatible with two relations to the same model.
- Has one relationship: This used a `booking_id` and `survey_id` but refused to set either of these fields.
- Has many relationship with a type field: Made it difficult to easily save the forms, as it wasn't possible to save to the single relationship. There was also no restriction on the number of forms.

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function booking()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Form::class, 'id', 'booking_form_id');
    }

    public function survey()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Form::class, 'id', 'survey_form_id');
    }
}

...

class Form extends Model
{
    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }
}

...

$event = new Event;
$event->name = 'Event';
$event->save();

$booking = new Form;
$booking->name = 'booking';
$event->booking()->save($booking);

$survey = new Form;
$survey->name = 'survey';
$event->survey()->save($survey);

...

Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');

    $table->string('name');

    $table->unsignedInteger('booking_form_id')->nullable()->index();
    $table->unsignedInteger('survey_form_id')->nullable()->index();

    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('name');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**What would be preferable:**

- Using a polymorphic relationship which would allow forms to be used in other parts of the application.
- Using multiple hasOne relationships to limit the number of forms to one for each type.

Comment: I am sorry..whats wrong with the relationship you already have ? :) I feel a bit lost..what scope is it not serving?

Comment: @Learner the scope not being served is that unfortunately what I have does not work correctly – it causes exceptions when trying to save the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got your param order wrong. It's [`hasOne($related, $foreignKey, $localKey)`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_hasOne)

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    /* if you haven't changed the default primary keys, $localKey should be equal to 'id' */ 
    public function booking()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Form::class, 'booking_form_id');
    }

    public function survey()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Form::class, 'survey_form_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Form extends Model
{
    public function booking_event()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Event::class, 'booking_form_id');
    }

    public function survey_event()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Event::class, 'survey_form_id');
    }
}
```

Now there's 2 ways you can go about this.

1. If a Form can belong to both kind of events, you need to return a collection when accessing `$form->event`.
2. If a Form can belong to only one kind of event, you need to guess which kind and return the model when accessing `$form->event`.

```php
# Form model
# 1. can be achieved using an accessor. Cannot be eager loaded but can be appended with the $appends Model property
public function getEventsAttribute()
{
    return collect([$this->booking_event, $this->survey_event]);
}
```

```php
# Form model
# 2. can be achieved using a relationship that guesses which relation it should return. Since it returns a relationship, it can be eager loaded.
public function event()
{
    return ($this->booking_event()->count() != 0) ? $this->booking_event() : $this->survey_event();
}
```

Comment: This triggers an exception with `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'booking_form_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into forms (name, booking_form_id, updated_at, created_at) values (booking, 2, 2019-11-05 16:32:34, 2019-11-05 16:32:34))` for me.

Comment: I have amended my question and added the insertion code to the bottom of the code block.

Comment: Now can you amend the question with the migration for Form and Event? The error was caused because a column doesn't exist so in order to see if I can edit my answer, I need to know what I'm working with.

Comment: I have amended with the migrations.

Comment: According to the migrations, the Event model should have belongsTo relationships and the Form model should have the hasOne relationships. I've edited my answer